# Specifying the load order of javascripts not working in Zikula

Tags: javascript, zikula

I am trying to get the JQuery ui library to load before zikula-bootstrap.js. This is required for certain pages to work properly that take advantage of JQuery ui widgets.

In a template the way to do this is to add pageAddAsset call. Here is a typical setup in a twig file?

```
{{ pageAddAsset('javascript', asset('jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js')) }}
{{ adminHeader() }}
<div class="container-fluid">
Twig cod here...
{{ adminFooter() }}
```

I would expect this would load the jquery-ui in its proper place, but it's inconsistent. This twig file works:
https://github.com/paustian/Book/blob/master/Resources/views/Admin/book_admin_modifybook.html.twig

This twig file doesn't
https://github.com/paustian/Book/blob/master/Resources/views/Admin/book_admin_modifybook.html.twig

I am stumped as to why. I have emptied the cache after updating the files. The error I get when this fails is in zikula-bootstrap.js "var bootstrapButton = $.fn.button.noConflict()" it says that button is undefined. Thanks for any help

Comment: not easy to guess where things go wrong for you; but see my comments in Slack for a possible clue

Answer (score 0):

This had to do with a bug in the core that Guite now has fixed. Adding the update fixed the problem. Thanks Guite!